# Excel Weekly Schedule Pivot Table

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table, pivot-chart

I'm creating a dashboard for a company with multiple employees at multiple locations. They want a schedule with slicers that shows them different locations or specific employee schedules. I'm wondering if something like [this](http://2rpfsk3299t51s5qfz1zwqve.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2016/07/12-Steps-to-a-Microsoft-Excel-Employee-Shift-Schedule.png) is possible using pivot tables? I want to be able to view each location of their stores separately which slicers would be perfect for but I can't seem to get a pivot table to look like the example given.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @pnuts is it possible period? Doesn't need to be just a pivot table that was just the first thought that came into my mind.

Comment: @pnuts Do you have any suggestions on where to start? Or what resources tackle a similar problem?

Comment: Where is the underlying data? In a PivotTable? If so,  you could use the GETPIVOTDATA function to dynamically populate those cells in a way that would respond to slicers. But the devil is in the detail